mixed model surival data
I am trying to build a model to assess the effect of a tree species genotypes and local environment on survival but I am not sure I am doing things right. I have collected multiple genotypes (GenotypeID) from different locations (LocationID) and have fragmented each genotype into three experimental units (ExperimentalUnitID. My experimental design consists of two gardens (GardenID), each containing three plots (PlotID), each containing two beds (BedID).
I would like to model the effect of genotype and location on survival at the last time point (SurvivalEnd). Would the following model do this?
glm_Survival <- glmer(
  SurvivalEnd ~ GenotypeID * LocationID + 
    (1| BedID) + (1| PlotID) + (1| GardenID)
  , data=data
  , family = binomial(link = "logit"))


Overall this looks appropriate.  A few questions.  1st, I don't see ExperimentalUnitID in the model.  Is this just a unique ID for each garden-plot-bed combo?   2nd, random effects with 2 levels (eg garden)  are possible to estimate but may be more appropriate as a fixed effect.  3rd, in terms of the biology, do the same genotypes occur in different locations (are they "crossed"?)

Also, as  gener suggestion, providing the model output is useful for spotting if anything is wonky.  There's a way to format it fixed width font so it looks like it's in R
